# Why is the A6 preprojective algebra of wild representation type?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, preprojective-algebra, wild-representation-type

As mentioned in the title, I would like to know a proof of the "well known" fact that the A<sub>6</sub> preprojective algebra is of wild representation type.

Ideally, I would like to see an explicit two-parameter family of indecomposable modules.

If you happen to prefer type D to type A and want to give an answer there, that would be appreciated too.

Comment: Related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/75956/indecomposable-modules-over-preprojective-algebras

Comment: There is a proof in [Erdmann-Skowronski: The stable Calabi-Yau dimension of tame symmetric algebras, Lemma 3.5 and Theorem 3.7]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inspired by the reference Julian gave in his comment, here's an explicit example of a two-parameter family of indecomposable representations.

First, I'll describe a one-parameter family of indecomposable representations for the preprojective algebra of type $A_5$.

Let $k$ be the coefficient field, and $\alpha\in k$. Then let $M(\alpha)$ be the representation
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
&\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}&&\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
&&\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&\alpha\end{pmatrix}
&&\begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix}\\
k&\rightleftarrows&k^2&\rightleftarrows&k^2&\rightleftarrows&k^2&
\rightleftarrows&k\\
&\begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix}&&\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}
&&\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
&&\begin{pmatrix}0\\\alpha\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{array}$$

It's a straightforward calculation to check that $M(\alpha)$ is indecomposable and that if $\alpha\neq\beta$ then any homomorphism $M(\alpha)\to M(\beta)$ is zero at the right hand vertex, so that a direct sum decomposition of $M(\alpha)\oplus M(\beta)$ into two non-zero summands is uniquely determined at the right hand vertex.

Now extend $M(\alpha)\oplus M(\beta)$ to a representation $N\left(\{\alpha,\beta\}\right)$ of the preprojective algebra of type $A_6$ by adding a vertex on the right hand end:
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
&&&&&&&&&\begin{pmatrix}0&0\end{pmatrix}\\
k\oplus k&\rightleftarrows&k^2\oplus k^2&\rightleftarrows&k^2\oplus k^2&\rightleftarrows&k^2\oplus k^2&
\rightleftarrows&k\oplus k&\rightleftarrows&k\\
&&&&&&&&&\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{array}$$

Then it follows easily from the properties stated for the representations $M(\alpha)$ that $N\left(\{\alpha,\beta\}\right)$ is indecomposable and $N\left(\{\alpha,\beta\}\right)\not\cong N\left(\{\alpha',\beta'\}\right)$ unless $\{\alpha,\beta\}=\{\alpha',\beta'\}$.

Comment: Nice. The statement that there are no Homs between M(alpha) and M(beta) is false, but irrelevant for proving the desired properties about N({alpha,beta}).

Comment: @PeterMcNamara Ah, you're right. But there are no Homs whose right hand component is non-zero, which is what is important to deduce that $N\left(\{\alpha,\beta\}\right)$ is indecomposable. I'll edit to correct this.

Comment: A similar construction also works in type D_5. You have a one parameter family for D_4 in dimension (1,1,2,1) (verticies numbered so that the third one is the central one). So Jeremy's construction gives a two-parameter family in dimension (2,2,4,2,1).